# ListPicker doesn't expand in StackPanel on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, stackpanel, listpicker

Another day another problem, this time I think with a simple issue into XAML formatting.

I have a ListPicker in a StackPanel on a XAML page in a WP7 app.  Whenever I tap the ListPicker, it expands, but it appears to expand behind the item below it.  If I have enough items in the list it opens in full screen mode which works fine.

Any suggestions, pointers would be appreciated;

```
<Grid Name="grdBought">

<StackPanel Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="480">
    <Button Name="btnSave" Grid.Row="0" Content="Save" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="378" Click="btnSave_Click" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">


            <toolkit:ListPicker Name="CategoryPicker" Header="Select Category" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" TabIndex="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="CategoryPicker_SelectionChanged" Height="100" Width="195">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryDesc}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="item" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" Text="{Binding CategoryDesc}" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>


            <StackPanel Name="Items" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Name="txtDescription" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="" Width="225" MaxLength="100" FontSize="40" InputScope="Text" />
                <TextBox Name="txtAmount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="0.00" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Width="163" KeyUp="txtAmount_KeyUp" />
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Name="tb1" Text="Amount" Height="27" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="137" />
    <Button Name="button1" Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="249,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />

</StackPanel>
```

I have been through the examples on the windowsphonegeek.com site, but I still can't make it work!

Comment: "It appears to expand behind the item below it." You sure? Or it doesn't expand at all?

Comment: Why are you setting the ListPicker height to 100? That's definitely a problem - a single item displayed is probably ~75 px, so you'd never see more than 1 of them. Don't set a height at all

Comment: It definitely expands - If I increase the Listpicker height property I can see it expand, it just doesn't push down the items below it in the StackPanel

Comment: @willmel - I removed the height value I'd set and it fixed my problem.  Thanks very much.  Can you post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting the Height of the ListPicker to 100. Remove that, and just leave as auto. This is an issue b/c when you restrict the height, the listpicker has nowhere to expand (thus, showing the behavior you're seeing)

Answer (score 0):

I guess height is creating an issue, just make sure that height of listpicker is greater than stackpanel.